# Translate days and months globally using react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, translation, react-i18next

The user can switch language from Swedish to English or English to Swedish. I can translate all the strings except the days of the week and months.

This is my i18n.js where the main translation utility lives.

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend'

// languages
import translationSv from '../locales/sv/translation.json'
import translationEn from '../locales/en/translation.json'

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: false,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
    fallbackLng: 'sv',
    keySeparator: false,
    load: 'languageOnly',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    resources: {
      sv: {
        translations: translationSv,
      },
      en: {
        translations: translationEn,
      },
    },
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    detection: {
      order: ['querystring', 'localStorage', 'navigator'],
      lookupQuerystring: 'lang',
      lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    },
  })

export default i18n
```

and in my dateHeader.js, i have the following codes:

```
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import Moment from 'react-moment'


const dateHeader = () => {
<Typography variant="body2">
  <Moment format="DD MMMM" subtract={{ days: 1 }}>
     {dateOfArrival}
  </Moment>
</Typography>
}
```

I added locale = "sv" in Moment but the days were changed PERMANENTLY to Swedish and I don't want that. I saw that onLanguageChanged can be used to change the language. I am new to this so I am confused on how to translate all days and months globally.

Comment: you can delete  days of the week and month from 'translation.json'

Answer (score 0):

You can get current language from [`i18next.language`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language):

```js
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import Moment from 'react-moment'

import i18n from './src/i18n.js' // IMPORT YOUR CONFIGURATION

const dateHeader = () => {
<Typography variant="body2">
  <Moment format="DD MMMM" subtract={{ days: 1 }} locale="{{ i18n.language }}">
                                               // ^-- ADD DYNAMIC LOCALE
     {dateOfArrival}
  </Moment>
</Typography>
}
```